# How to convert 2021-05-31T02:40:05.2Z String to Date Object TimeZone (GMT+7) Java android

Tags: java, android

i am trying to convert ISO datetime 2021-05-31T02:40:05.2Z to dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss (GMT +7) in Java language (Android). I have tried many ways but still not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH3Lc.png)

Comment: If by *Date Object* you meant `java.util.Date`, two comments: (1) You can’t, a `Date` cannot have a time zone. (2) The `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated. Consider using `ZonedDateTime`or `OffsetDateTime` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
Instant                               // Represent a moment as seen in UTC, with a resolution of nanoseconds.
.parse(                               
    "2021-05-31T02:40:05.2Z"          // Standard ISO 8601 format. `Z` on end means UTC (an offset of zero). 
)                                     // Returns an `Instant` object.
.atZone(                              // Adjust from UTC to some time zone.
    ZoneId.of( "Antarctica/Davis" )   // Specify desired/expected time zone.
)                                     // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toString()                           // Returns a `String` object whose text represents the value within the `ZonedDateTime` in standard ISO 8601 format extended to append the name of the zone in square brackets.
```

Run [live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/mF0oEj).

> 2021-05-31T09:40:05.200+07:00[Antarctica/Davis]

## Details

Never use the legacy classes `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and so on.

Parse your standard ISO 8601 input string as a [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), a moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). The `Z` on end tells us this date and time is meant to be seen as having an offset of zero.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2021-05-31T02:40:05.2Z" ) ;
```

Specify your intended [time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). You mentioned an offset of `+07:00`. Many time zones may share that particular offset on particular dates. I will arbitrarily choose `Asia/Tomsk`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tomsk" ) ;
```

Apply that time zone ([`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to the `Instant` object to obtain a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/mF0oEj).

> zdt.toString(): 2021-05-31T09:40:05.200+07:00[Asia/Tomsk]

All this has been addressed many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]